# How can I point to a url full of json value and eval parse it, using json2.js?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, function, url

How can I parse this into an eval object with json2 dot js?

There is a url http: //blah.com/json.data that I want to call from a button like this

`<input type="button" value"Go" onclick="go()" />`

from the Go javascript function, I want to hit the blah url that simply has this type of data-content (it has no html) on the page:
    userdetails.attribute.name=LastName
    userdetails.attribute.value=Smith
    userdetails.attribute.name=GivenName
    userdetails.attribute.value=Michael

How can I use the `eval()` function to throw all of the data from that blah url into a var object1 so that I can do something like this:

`document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML = object1.blah[1].LastName;`

Thanks in advanced...I'm new to json2 but would like to start using it.

Comment: You need to use ajax.
If you are willing to use jQuery (which you should), read [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I would love to. I know how to download a jQuery library too, wink. Can you give me a sample javascript code implementation given the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.get({
  url: "/json.data",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (result) {
    $("#lname").text(result.blah[1].LastName);
  }
});
```

If your data is actually formatted as you posted in your example (which is not valid JSON), you may need to parse it by hand. You can tell jQuery to send you plain text instead of attempting to parse the response by setting the `dataType` setting to `text`.

Comment: I see what you are talking about. I still need to write parse routines since the json format is not valid, bummer.